# What is a comprehensive document from STM for PCB design using their STM32F302C8 MCU?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, stm32, eaglecad

I have to design a STM32 based PCB and connect it to peripheral sensors that will communicate using 3 Analogue Pins and 5 digital.

I have found documents from STM on oscillator placement and EMC design considerations.

Will these documents contain all that I need or are there any more which will make my job faster?

I am mostly just concerned about this thing blowing up in my face due to the lack of a pull-up or pull-down resistor.

Comment: For several STM32 MCU lines, there is a *Getting Started* guide. Not so for the STM32F3. But I still suggest read one of them, e.g. [Getting Started With STM32F4xxxx](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00115714-getting-started-with-stm32f4xxxx-mcu-hardware-development-stmicroelectronics.pdf). In my experience, proper placement of crystal and decoupling capacitors is required but not difficult. If your analog signals need to be very precise and noise-free, then you should focus on that part. Pull-up and pull-down resistors aren't required except for application specific purposes.

Comment: @Codo is this pdf you have given the link to universal for most STM MCUs?

Comment: The F4 and F3 series are similar enough so it applies as well. I would be more careful with the H series and it might not cover low-power aspects of newer series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any general MCU, some of the usual considerations:

- The oscillator needs to be as close to the MCU as possible. The manual will advise what capacitors to use. Often you get layout advise too, particularly if the part uses external PLL filters and similar.
- The analog supply and ref voltage may need to be treated with some special care in case you are doing high precision ADC measurements. It's often routed to the opposite side of the MCU part compared to the oscillator, for this very reason. You might want to use a seperate clean supply for the analog parts depending on your requirements.
- Decoupling caps on all supply pins. Usually the manufacturer makes recommendations. Otherwise 100nF ceramics are most commonly used as a "one size fits all".
- It is often advised to place an external pull-up on the /reset pin. Modern MCUs come with an internal one, but you might want one with lower resistance (4k7 or 10k) for EMC reasons. Particularly if you drag the /reset line out to a programming connector, which is almost always the case.
- Be *very* careful with what cap you place on the /reset pin. The manufacturer should make a recommendation here. You need a cap there for EMC reasons, but it shouldn't be allowed to mess up the reset cycle of the MCU. Too high a value here and the MCU might get stuck in reset. Hard to troubleshoot.
- Consider the situation where the programming connector (SWD/JTAG etc) is allowed to supply the board vs the situation where it just needs to "sniff" the supply of the board to set its own logic levels. If you connect this the wrong way, like letting the programming interface feed 3V3 straight into your 3V3 plane, you might blow up your voltage regulators since they never like the situation Vin=0V, Vout=3V3. This can also cause very hard to find problems, like a voltage regulator surviving the blow but failing some months later out in the field.

Comment: Except with STM32 MCUs, it is recommended to not have any pull up on the reset pin, due to it being internal, and external resistor can alter the reset timing. And standard STM32 JTAG/SWD programming tools need direct access to MCU VCC so the tool can use the same VCC when communicating with the MCU. Otherwise I agree with with the items you said, which basically boils down to "do what MCU docs say and if they don't say anything then do it like this".

Answer (score 1):

Read the datasheet, reference manual, and application notes, especially the one called getting started with hardware design guide.

Comment: Sir I tried looking for the ones called Getting Started with Hardware design guides for STM32F302C8T6 but I am just unable to find.

Comment: @ShridharSharma I just found one AN1709 "EMC design guide for STM8, STM32 and Legacy MCUs 3.1". It wasn't all that helpful, but it had a few good tips here and there.

Comment: @Lundin excatly, I do not want to F up.

Comment: @ShridharSharma Yeah well it's very rare that the first prototype board is flawless. Usually takes some 2-3 revisions to nail everything down.